# What does |lang| part mean in this each method? Where does this come from?

Tags: ruby

I am reading through Chris Pine's Learn To Program chapter 7 Arrays and Iterators. 
He introduces the each method with the following example:

```
languages = ['English', 'German', 'Ruby']

languages.each do |lang|
  puts 'I love ' + lang + '!'
  puts 'Don\'t you?'
end

puts 'And let\'s hear it for C++!'
puts '...'
```

It's not hard to understand how it works overall, but I can't figure out where the `|lang|` part is coming from so out of blue. Shouldn't it be assigned/named or something before it can be used like this? So the computer can know what the "lang" refers to? Does `||` do something wrapping around `lang`? Or does ruby just know what `lang` means?

I am afraid the question is too basic, but I am hoping someone might help me just a bit...

Comment: Did you read the text after the code snippet which explains all: *"Translating into English, the above program reads something like: For `each` object in `languages`, point the variable `lang` to the object and then do everything I tell you to, until you come to the end."*

Comment: You need to work through a good Ruby tutorial. `|lang|` is how Ruby denotes parameters to a block, which would be covered very early.

Comment: Thank you everyone for the help!! I think I got it now. The each method basically yields AND assign with || at the same time, right? :) And Kev, I read that text as well, but it didn't initially make sense to me since there was no mention of "a variable" before "the variable".

Comment: PS. It's wonderful how everybody explains the same thing a bit differently, and they all help me reinforce my understanding of this. Thanks!

Comment: @gballoon - genuine apologies, didn't mean for that to sound flippant. Thought maybe you'd not read that far.

Comment: @theTinMan I find that no matter how good of a tutorial is, I find the contents hard to digest as a newbie since all the words are so obscure. For example, I wouldn't really get what "Ruby denotes parameters to a block" means if I didn't have my own initial question to work with that explanation. For this reason I am grateful I can come here to ask... Thanks for the advice though!

Answer (score 4):

`lang` is a variable used to hold an element from the `languages` array. Any variable inside `||` will be used to grab single element from array. So, every time the loops executes, an element from the array is popped out and held in an variable named `lang` and data held by `lang` is displayed using `puts` method.

Answer (score 3):

The `each` method yields every element one by one and it gets assigned to the variable `lang`.

Internally, the `each` method is implemented something like this:

```
def each
  index = 0
  while index < array.length
     yield array[index]
     index += 1
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

`|lang|` is a block variable.  If you strip down your code, you can see that the `.each` method is iterating over the `languages` array and assigning array elements to the block variable:

```
languages = ['English', 'German', 'Ruby']

languages.each do |lang|
  puts lang
end

#=> English
#=> German
#=> Ruby
```

Multi-line blocks use a `do/end` syntax (as in your example), and single-line blocks use a braces syntax.  For example:

```
languages = ['English', 'German', 'Ruby']

languages.each { |lang| puts lang}
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like, in the above example, you created an array storing multiple language variables.

You then iterated over all three elements in the array and represented each one with a variable called **lang**.

lang, which is inside the brackets is simply a variable.

Hope this helped you